# How to instruct jupyter to use python2 not python3

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Given a `PYTHONPATH` that seems to point to `python` :

```
cat $(which jupyter)

#!/bin/bash
JUPYTER_PATH="/usr/local/etc/jupyter" 

PYTHONPATH="/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_1/libexec/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_1/libexec/vendor/lib/python2.7/site-packages:
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages" 
exec "/usr/local/Cellar/jupyter/1.0.0_1/libexec/bin/jupyter" "$@"
```

Then why does the `jupyter notebook` report python3?

[image]

(btw: how to resize that image smaller - but with only scaling not cropping?  I tried adding `s` and it only cropped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you open a new notebook you can choose what version of python you want to use

Comment: I see - it is on the `kernels | change kernel`